# download image from gridview in to pdf

Tags: asp.net

I need to download gridview which contains images.Same image will get repeated multiple times in the gridview which needs to be downloaded in an pdf format.Pls help or guide me to achieve the result.

Comment: Same image repeated ? Do You want to download this image as PDF ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I suggest you should use iTextSharp! http://itextpdf.com/

Comment: yeah i tried itextsharp but not able to achieve the result

Comment: @zey yes the same image will get repeated multiple time in the gridview and it needs to be downloaded

Comment: Can you show me your code , what have you tried with `iTextSharp` ?